# What do i return in this method c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to return the name of the song, the name of the artist and the number of copies sold. The only thing that seems to compile in the return is the method name which can't be right as it will just cause it to be an infinite loop.

Also in the loop how do I change the tryparse so it also doesn't accept negative numbers?

The code is below

```cs
namespace Songs
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            object [] ArrayOfSongs;
            ArrayOfSongs = new object[4];

            for (int i = 4; i < ArrayOfSongs.Length; i++)
            {
                ArrayOfSongs[i] = InputSongDetails();
                var store = InputSongDetails();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Enter an artists name, or press return for all artists");
        }

        static Song InputSongDetails()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("What is the name of your song");
            string name = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("What is the artists name");
            string artist = Console.ReadLine();

            int records;
            Console.WriteLine("How many records did it sell");
            while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out records))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("That is not valid please enter a number");
            }
            string returns = $"Your song is{name}, the artists name is {artist} and it sold {records} records";
            return InputSongDetails();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my song class

```
namespace Songs
```

{
    class Song
    {
        string name;
        string artist;
        int copiesSold;

```
    public Song(string name, string artist, int copiesSold)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.artist = artist;
        this.copiesSold = copiesSold;
    }

    public Song()
    {
    }

    public string GetArtist()
    {
        return artist;
    }

    public string GetDetails()
    {
        return $"Name: {name} Artist: {artist} Copies Sold: {copiesSold},";
    }

    public string GetCertification()
    {
        if (copiesSold<200000)
        {
            return null;
        }
        if (copiesSold<400000)
        {
            return "Silver";
        }
        if (copiesSold<600000)
        {
            return "gold";
        }
        return "Platinum";  
    }
}
```

}

Comment: There is a `TryParse` that takes a `NumberStyles`; `NumberStyles` includes the ability to enable/disable negatives... so... `NumberStyles.Integer & ~NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign` should work...

Comment: Where is the song class?

Comment: or simpler `while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out records) || records < 0)`

Comment: The for-loop can never run, because 4 is the length of the array..

Comment: Wow! nice catch @NineBerry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well according to your method signature you're returning something resembling a `Song`:

```
static Song InputSongDetails()
```

Ideally you will have a class called `Song` defined somewhere which looks something like this:

```
class Song
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Artist { get; set; }
    public int Records { get; set; }
}
```

So, your return should look something like this:

```
return new Song
{
    Name = name,
    Artist = artist,
    Records = records
};
```

For your loop, just add an additional condition to there `while` clause:

```
while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out records) || records < 0)
```

UPDATE:

Based on your newly revealed `Song` class just return a new instance using the fist constructor:

```
return new Song(name, artist, records);
```

Comment: Well, technically the signature does not demand a **class** called _Song_ (or a class implementing an interface called _Song_ for that matter). _Song_ could also be realized as a **struct**. But in terms of practical advice, i agree with making _Song_ a class...

Comment: @preciousbetine, why not?

Comment: @preciousbetine It would had I remembered to declare the `records` variable properly... fixed now!

Comment: @elgonzo Darn it! Unfixed now... And thanks for pointing out the specifics of the return type - I've updated my answer :)

Comment: This condition `records < 0`should be checked within the body of the loop.

Comment: @preciousbetine, no it is not necessary to do that within the body. Whether you prefer this or that style is not the point. You claimed it doesn't work. But it does.

Comment: @preciousbetine: It works fine as Kallum has it now... Test it yourself if you are unsure!

Comment: @preciousbetine Putting it within the body would require the unnecessary use of `continue`, why not keep it as a `while` condition which is also more semantic?

Comment: @KallumTanton Iv'e just added my song class in the question if that makes it any clearer

Comment: @Umarfarooq99 I've updated my answer to accommodate this :)

Comment: @KallumTanton How would I unit test the method to see it works?

Answer (score 0):

The compiler will not *prevent* you from creating an infinite loop. What I *think* you want to return is a new `Song` object (guessing on the property names):

```
  return new Song() {
      Name = name,
      Artist = artist,
      Records = records
  };
```

> Also in the loop how do I change the tryparse so it also doesn't accept negative numbers?

Put the `tryparse` in a `while` loop that exits if the parsed value is "valid" based on whatever criteria you want.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have a Song class like this

```
public class Song {
    public string Name {get; set; }
    public string Artist {get;set; }
    public int Records {get;set; }
}
```

Then you have to return a new Song object in your InputSongDetails method

```
static Song InputSongDetails()
{
    var song = new Song();
    Console.WriteLine("What is the name of your song");
    song.Name = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("What is the artists name");
    song.Artist = Console.ReadLine();

    int records;
    Console.WriteLine("How many records did it sell");
    while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out records))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("That is not valid please enter a number");
    }
    song.Records = records;
    string returns = String.Format("Your song is{0}, the artists name is {1} and it sold {2} records", song.Name, song.Artist, song.Records);

    return song;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated to use the op's class

```
using System;


namespace Songs
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Song[] ArrayOfSongs = new Song[4];

        for (var i = 0; i < ArrayOfSongs.Length; i++)
        {

            ArrayOfSongs[i] = InputSongDetails();

        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static Song InputSongDetails()
    {
        //Song returnObj = new ExpandoObject();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter an artists name, or press return for all artists");
        Console.WriteLine("What is the name of your song");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();
       // returnObj.name = name;
        Console.WriteLine("What is the artists name");
        string artist = Console.ReadLine();
        //returnObj.artist = artist;
        Console.WriteLine("How many records did it sell");
        string recordsStr = Console.ReadLine();
        int records;
        while (!Int32.TryParse(recordsStr, out records) || records < 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("try again");
            recordsStr = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        //returnObj.records = records;
        Console.WriteLine($"Your song is{name}, the artists name is {artist} and it sold {records.ToString()} records");
        return new Song(name,artist,records);

    }
}

 class Song
{
    string name; string artist; int copiesSold;

    public Song(string name, string artist, int copiesSold)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.artist = artist;
        this.copiesSold = copiesSold;
    }

    public Song()
    {
    }

    public string GetArtist()
    {
        return artist;
    }

    public string GetDetails()
    {
        return $"Name: {name} Artist: {artist} Copies Sold: {copiesSold},";
    }

    public string GetCertification()
    {
        if (copiesSold < 200000)
        {
            return null;
        }
        if (copiesSold < 400000)
        {
            return "Silver";
        }
        if (copiesSold < 600000)
        {
            return "gold";
        }
        return "Platinum";
    }
}

}
```